# How to display dash line into p:tree

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm interested how I can display dash line into `p:tree`?
In this [tutorial](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeAjax.jsf) there is no dash line maybe the only way is to add it manually.

Is there a way to add it?

Comment: I'd suggest posting this on the Primefaces Forum. Think you'll get a better answer there ;)

Comment: What do you mean be dashed line??

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using CSS selectors.

Internally Primefaces v.2 use a YUI tree view, so the CSS classes are the same - they're documented [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/).

Primefaces v.3 I think use their own set of CSS classes for the tree view - you can either find them in the documentation or  figure them out analysing the showcase example using e.g. Firebug.